# On FreeBSD, how to find packages depending on a specific package

Tags: freebsd, pkg

I want to find/list/search packages depending on a specific package on FreeBSD with `pkg` tool. How can I do that? Something like:

`# pkg list dependent-upon llvm40` ???

Answer (score 4):

Running `$ man pkg-info`, I see:

```
OPTIONS
     The following options are supported by pkg info:

     -r, --required-by
             Display the list of packages which require pkg-name.
```

I tested and it works:

```
$ pkg info -r llvm40
llvm40-4.0.1:
        mesa-dri-17.1.7
```

Comment: Note that this would only search amongst your installed packages, not all packages in the repository.

Comment: Though I would hardly be interested in knowing all the packages requiring `perl5` in all the ports (...)